# Add flutter to existing android app "Cannot resolve symbol Flutter"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to add flutter module in existing android app from medium articles and some YouTube videos and step by step follows the instructions.But problem is if i try to add this code in `MainActivity.java` then it shows me an error "Cannot resolve symbol Flutter", means if i type `Flutter.` then it doesn't show me `createView`. Is it the code has been changed?

```
View flutterView=Flutter.createView(MainActivity.this,getLifecycle(),"r1");
FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayout=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
addContentView(flutterView,frameLayout);
```

Comment: did u add flutter dependencies?

Comment: @SanjaySharma yes i added the flutter dependencies `implementation project(':flutter')`

Comment: Did you add this in settings.gradle 
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))                                
evaluate(new File(
  settingsDir.parentFile,
  'my_flutter/.android/include_flutter.groovy'
))

Comment: @SanjaySharma yes.

Comment: Did u try to clean gradle cache and rebuild it

Comment: @SanjaySharma It doesn't work after gradle cache clean

Comment: Is your project on github?

Comment: @SanjaySharma no its not.

Comment: try to build the project and run it. Sometimes the dependency won't be visible directly and added at runtime. Just try to build the project and make proper imports even if they show error in Android Studio

Comment: did you follow these instructions? I don't them using Flutter.createView! https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app

Answer (score 2):

Me too. Flutter.createView is not working.
But I found this solution.
In your Manifest.xml, add meta-data for Flutter.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Fludroid.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.Entrypoint"
            android:value="main"
            />
    </activity>
```

use FlutterView in your layout file

```
<io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView
    android:id="@+id/flutter_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

attach Flutter in your Activity's onCreate method

```
if (flutterEngine == null) {
        flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(requireContext())
        flutterEngine!!.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
            DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint(FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath(), "main")
        )
    }
    flutterView = view.findViewById(R.id.flutter_view)
    flutterView?.attachToFlutterEngine(flutterEngine!!)
```

add @pragma('vm:entry-point') in main.dart

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
```

Good Luck.